# Split Array into 2D based on 2 parameters C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file which I have split up into a string array based on new line.

string[] arr = s.Split('\n');

Now, I need to further categorize this into a 2-dimensional array wherein each column is a new "transaction". 
So the text file basically contains info about bank transactions, an example being given below:

21......
22....
23.....
31....
32.....
31.....
32.....
21....
21.....
22....

The beginning of the numbers signify a new tx record which begins at a new line. I want to make it into a 2D array wherein each column is grouped as one tx beginning from 21 until it comes across the next 21 (so the record before it).

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].StartsWith("21")) 
            {
                indices[i] = i;
            }
        }
```

I tried to write the code above to check for array element beginning with 21 and then storing the index but it ends up storing all the indices.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `arr[i].Split(new string[] { "21"}, StringSplitOptions.None);`?

Comment: no i tried this, in this case in the array there are 2 elements in one column every time there's a 21, but if there isn't a 21, it becomes a new array element. I want it group UNTIL it finds the next 21, not simply at 21.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't follow you. Could you, please, provide the *desired outcome* for the line's example? E.g. if we are given 
`"21 A 22 B 23 C 31 D 32 E 31 F 32 G 21 H 21 I 22 J"` shall the result be 
`["21 A 22 B 23 C 31 D 32 E 31 F 32 G", "21 H", "21 I 22 J"]`?

Comment: The desired outcome should be [ "21... 22... 23...", "21.... 22... 23..", "21...., 22...., 23..."] so every column should start with a transaction record which begins with 21 and then the next row in that column will be 22-something and so on so forth. So every column starts with a 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd need to do is

```
string[] arr = s.Split('\n');

List<List<string>> listOfLists = new List<List<string>>(); //dynamic multi-dimensional list

//list to hold the lines after the line with "21" and that line
List<string> newList = new List<string>();  
listOfLists.Add(newList);

for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].StartsWith("21"))
    {
        if(newList.Count > 0)
        {                
            newList = new List<string>();  //make a new list for a column
            listOfLists.Add(newList);      //add the list of lines (one column) to the main list
        }
    }
    newList.Add(arr[i]);  //add the line to a column
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you can try *regular expressions* (i.e. instead of *splitting*, *extract* transactions):

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ... 

  string line = "21 A 22 B 23 C 31 D 32 E 31 F 32 G 21 H 21 I 22 J";

  var result = Regex
    .Matches(line, "21 .*?((?=21 )|$)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray(); // <- let's materialize as na array

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
21 A 22 B 23 C 31 D 32 E 31 F 32 G 
21 H 
21 I 22 J
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work :( Of coz the desired outcome should be as I replied to your previous comment, but even this one doesnt work :(

Comment: @RicheekDey doesn't work *how*? this looks exactly like what you requested

Comment: Well, debugger shows results is {string[0]} and console window shows no output either.